# Pre tax and and after tax on dental and eye vision insurance

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, paycheck

If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. In my Pay stubs I realize i get tax pre tax and post tax on both my dental and vision insurance? why is that? why do they take it out twice?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Do you have a domestic partner on your benefits?

Comment: I live in United States of America, New York. and yes I do have a Domestic Partner in my benefit

Answer (score 3):

Domestic partner benefits are generally not qualified for tax-exempt status under employer Section 125 cafeteria plans.  This is an IRS regulation that has nothing to do with your particular plan.

What you're seeing is the tax-free contribution for yourself (and possibly dependents), and an after tax contribution for your domestic partner.  Sometimes this appears as a separate contribution, sometimes the contribution toward the domestic partner is imputed as income and taxed that way.